# I have sitemap for my blog but sitemap.xml doesnt update

Tags: php, xml

Im having issue with sitemap.xml i have automatic sitemap.php and after i created 2 post it succesfully created xml's of these atricles but i created 2 more articles but sitemap doesnt update. I have Cron Jobs for 15 minutes it automaticly activates sitemap.php. How can i fix it i have this code for sitemap.php (i cant use snippet im using tablet)

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$sqlSitemap = "SELECT * FROM articles";
$resultSitemap = $conn->query($sqlSitemap);

// Start building the XML
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' . PHP_EOL;

// Loop through articles and add them to the XML
while ($rowSitemap = $resultSitemap->fetch_assoc()) {
    $url = 'https://bilimevreni.com/makale?id=' . $rowSitemap['id'];
    $xml .= '<url>' . PHP_EOL;
    $xml .= '<loc>' . htmlspecialchars($url) . '</loc>' . PHP_EOL;
    $xml .= '<lastmod>' . date('c') . '</lastmod>' . PHP_EOL;
    $xml .= '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' . PHP_EOL;
    $xml .= '</url>' . PHP_EOL; 
}

// Close the XML
$xml .= '</urlset>';

// Save the XML to sitemap.xml
file_put_contents('sitemap.xml', $xml);

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: looks like you need to run sitemap.php after a post is created to create the sitemap.xml

Comment: Did you wait the 15 minutes before checking the sitemap? Did you check that the 2 new  Articles actually exist on the database?

Comment: Might be worth sorting the query, so new articles appear at the top or bottom of the xml file rather than a random order. Maybe they are just lost in the crowd

Comment: Im checking for 3 days and there is only 2 xml not much i cant lose it

Comment: Are there 4 Articles on the database in the `articles` table?

Comment: yes there are 4 articles in the articles table here is the website: https://www.bilimevreni.com

Comment: Then as long as your `db.php` is connecting to the right database you shold get 4 articles in the XML. So if you dont look at your CRON to see why it is not running! Or maybe the cron is getting errors! Or maybe as it runs in a different fodler, it is putting the new xml file somewhere OTHER than the web site folder

Comment: i checked and there are no other xml files and db.php is connecting successfully and i asked to the host they said cron is successfuly activated. i dont know that is the problem it stucked

Comment: This `file_put_contents('sitemap.xml', $xml);` writes a file to the Current Working Directory. That will be different when run from the CLI and the Website and a CRON Job. Try specifying a fully qualified directory. Then you will either see the file OR get a error message probably involving lack of privilages

Comment: i did specify to public_html i will wait if its working or i will write thanks for you help tho

Comment: Make sure you know where errors are written, you shoudl have access to that file

Comment: It worked i guess i will look it for a few days after that i will feedback

Comment: I checked it and it worked i created New post yesterday and i looked right now its added to the xml thanks a lot